# Type error in Cross_val_score Python sklearn.model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, cross-validation

I am creating a neural network that distinguishes between malignant and benign skin tumors using computer vision. I want to perform a k-fold validation with `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, y=None, *, groups=None, scoring=None, cv=None, n_jobs=None, verbose=0, fit_params=None, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', error_score=nan)` but I think the error I have is that I don't know how to enter the **y** parameter correctly.[Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgrfW.jpg)

In an excel file I have by columns the following parameters: **image_name patient_id esion_id sex age_approx anatom_site_general_challenge diagnosis target path_jpeg**[Excell display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbypG.jpg)

I guess I should enter in the parameter **y** the value of target for each image, but I don't know how to do it.

In the images folder of the training and test there are only 584 images of each class in total while in the excel there are 33126 images.[Input images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAsjs.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance and I am sorry if the post is not correctly written and explained, it is the first one I do and I am open to criticism and learning. Best regards.

```
data_excel = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vicral/Desktop/TFG/Udemy/Deep Learning A-Z/Ejemplo con jupiter/M/ISIC_2020_Training_GroundTruth_v2 (1).csv')

df1_styler = data_excel.head().style.set_table_attributes("style='display:inline'").set_caption('Head Train Data')
display_html(df1_styler._repr_html_(), raw=True)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('M/Train2',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 50,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary') 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('M/Test2',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 50,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 64, 3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = 'accuracy')
cnn.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 10, shuffle=False, verbose=1)

# define the iterator to perform 5-fold cross-validation
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
# perform cross-validation on X, y
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
results = cross_val_score(cnn, training_set, None, cv=kf)
# print the result
print(f"Final Cross-Validation Loss = {abs(results.mean()):.4f}")
```

Comment: As the error says, you need to provide a scoring parameter to the cross_val_score. Try passing scoring='accuracy'

Comment: It doesen´t work neither.

Comment: y value is your target column in the csv. you can grab it and drop it from the csv. y_value=data_excel['target'] and data_excel.drop(columns=['target'], inplace=True) and post all the imports you made

Comment: `training_set.labels` Here I have the labels of each image of the training (1058 in total) and I think it is the y_value.

So maybe the problem is in the X value. Should I send the images to the cross_val_score function?

The images are in `training_set`?

The output of that: `len(training_set)` is 34 and I dont know why